# Change Boarding Point of a CKWL ticket

Tags: tickets, indian-railways, tatkal, irctc

I booked a tatkal ticket today from IRCTC and got CKWL 2.
I wanted to change the boarding point of the journey, so I tried to change boarding point option on the IRCTC website.Unfortunately, I was unable to do so because on clicking the button, nothing happened. Can someone please tell me what the issue can be or is it not possible to change boarding point of CKWL tickets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edited after suggestion from @CMaster:

I tried google to find a solution for the same but unfortunately nothing was available, so I communicated with the customer-care of IRCTC (011-39340000) and asked for the relevant solution. The executive told me that the same was not possible for tickets having CKWL status. Later when my ticket was confirmed(status changed to CNF), I tried changing the boarding point again from the IRCTC website and the same was done without any hassle.

Comment: I tried google to find a solution for the same but unfortunately nothing was available, so I communicated with the customer-care of IRCTC (011-39340000) and asked for the relevant solution. The executive told me that the same was not possible for tickets having CKWL status. Later when my ticket was confirmed, I tried changing the boarding point again from the IRCTC website and the same was done without any hassle.

Comment: @NamanSharma Edit a mention of some of that in your answer, would you (ie, that you found this out from the support phone number, and then it worked when you tried it)